# How do I grab values from datafile to make legend?

Tags: loops, printf, gnuplot, system, call

I want to use system call(s) to grab values from first data line in file file and print into legend of plot.

The command returns a syntax error. I admit come confusion about a- the use of system calls and syntax, despite reading  few advanced questions here.

This is what I have:

gnuplot> plot for [i=20:30:1] '4He-processed' index i u 8:($22>0.2&&$22<2?$9:1/0):10 w yerr  t system("head -2 4He-processed | tail -1 | awk '{printf "%s %8.3f %8.3f %s" , "'", $3, $4,"'"}'")

> with the response: ')' expected with the pointer at the "f" in printf.

I want to have the values in $3 and $4 written to the legend.

This alternate command

gnuplot>  plot for [i=20:30:1] '4He-processed' index i u 8:($22>0.2&&$22<2?$9:1/0):10 w yerr  t system("head -2 4He-processed | tail -1 ")

puts the entire first line, of each index loop, to the legend

It likely has to do with syntax?

I want the values from $3 and $4, not the column headings:

Here is the some lines (but not all the columns) from the file

## nz   na    e0       theta     nu      xsect         ert         y        fy         fye

```
2    4    0.150   60.000    0.025   0.330E+02   0.752E+00   -0.0459   0.956E+00   0.218E-01 
2    4    0.150   60.000    0.030   0.497E+02   0.784E+00   -0.0001   0.146E+01   0.230E-01 
2    4    0.150   60.000    0.035   0.483E+02   0.766E+00    0.0315   0.144E+01   0.229E-01 
2    4    0.150   60.000    0.040   0.408E+02   0.728E+00    0.0573   0.125E+01   0.224E-01
```

This continues for many blocks. Here, if I were to start my loop with the first block, the values (at $3 and $4) would be 0.150 and 60.000  which correspond to the energy and angle of the projectile and they would hopefully appear in the legend. The plotted quantities ($8,$22 and $23) not pasted here (too many columns).

Comment: Can you please give a few lines of real example data?

Comment: Thanks for adding data. But I still don't have a full picture how your data exactly looks like. So, I understand now, you have at least 30 of such blocks separated by two blank lines. Does each of these blocks have a text header line or not? Furthermore, is it correct that column 3 and 4 are constant within each block?

Comment: Yes. and Yes. That is why I piped the first system call into the second. I only need a single line from the data block to make the legend for that block.

Comment: A solution which I have in mind will depend on the gnuplot version. Which version of gnuplot are you running? 5.2 or 5.4 ?

Comment: I am using Version 5.4 patchlevel 1    last modified 2020-12-01

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? If yes, then please accept one of the answers, indicating that your question is answered. The same for your earlier question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the double-quoted string in your command starts with `head"` and runs to `printf"`.   That is clearly not what you intended.

Also I am uncertain what you mean by  `values in $3 and $4`. Can you show an example of the first line (2 lines?) of your file and state, in words, what you are trying to extract from it?

---

**Amended answer after seeing the data and a fuller explanation of the requirements**

The answer from @theozh should work, but for completeness here is a different approach that works in either gnuplot 5.2 or 5.4.
It uses two passes through the data file; one pass to construct the titles, and a second pass for the actual plot.

```
$Data <<EOD
nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   11  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   12  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   13  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   14  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10


nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   21  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   22  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   23  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   24  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10


nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   31  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   32  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   33  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   34  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
EOD

set key out
set key title "e0 theta" left
#set datafile columnheader # omit this line for gnuplot version < 5.4
                           # columheaders are not actually used anyhow

#
# First pass is just to accummulate an array of titles
#
nblocks = 30         # maximum number of data blocks
array Title[nblocks] # one title for each data blockA
set term push        # remember current terminal
set term dumb        # could be anything
set out '/dev/null'  # throw away the output

plot for [i=0:2:1] $Data index i using 1:2:($0 == 1 ? Title[i+1]=sprintf("%g %g",$3,$4) : "") with labels

#
# Second pass is the actual plot
#
set term pop         # restore original terminal

plot for [i=0:2:1] $Data index i using 1:2 with lp title Title[i+1]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work to paste multiple lines into a comment - the format is lost. Please edit your original question to contain these lines in a quoted block.  Also please clarify what the title (titles?) should contain.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't use `columnheader()` (check `help columnheader`), because by this you will sacrifice the first data line of each block and I assume you do want to keep all data.

The following should work for gnuplot>=5.4.0 and under the assumption that column 3 and 4 do not change within each block. However, this will not work for gnuplot<=5.4.0, because (as I understand) the title for the legend will be evaluated *before* each plotting iteration and in gnuplot>=5.4.0 *after* each plotting iteration. For gnuplot<5.4.0 you have to think about other workarounds.

I hope you get the idea and can adapt the script to your case, i.e. filtering, etc.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0)

```
### extract title without using columnheader()
reset session

$Data <<EOD
nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   11  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   12  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   13  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   14  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10


nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   21  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   22  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   23  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   24  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10


nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   31  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   32  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   33  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   34  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
EOD

set key out

plot for [i=0:2:1] $Data u 1:2:(myTitle=sprintf("%g, %g",$3,$4)) index i \
     w p pt 7 ps 2 lc i title myTitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**  (script for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

What Ethan did in his answer with an array (available only from 5.2.0 on) you can do with strings and `word()` for older versions (check `help word`).
The following works for 4.6.0 and 4.6.5 and >=5.0.0, however, not for 4.6.7 (it complains that `... '+' u (NaN):(NaN) ...` "Skipping data file with no valid points").

For gnuplot 4.x you cannot add spaces in your `myTitles`, but for gnuplot>=5.0.0 you could use double quotes and include spaces, e.g. `myTitles=myTitles.sprintf(' "%g, %g"',$3,$4)`.

You might have to adapt the color numbers in the second plot command depending on which subblocks (`index`) you are plotting in the first plot command.

**Data:** `SO74320605.dat`

```
nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   11  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   12  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   13  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   14  0.150  60.000  5   6     7   8  9  10


nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   21  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   22  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   23  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   24  0.250  65.000  5   6     7   8  9  10


nz   na  e0     theta   nu  xsect ert y  fy fye
 1   31  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 2   32  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 3   33  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
 4   34  0.350  70.000  5   6     7   8  9  10
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot 4.6.0, 4.6.5, >=5.0.0, but not for 4.6.7)

```
### extract title from lines without using columnheader()
reset

FILE = "SO74320605.dat"

set key out noautotitle
myTitles = ''

plot for [i=0:2:1] FILE u 1:2:($0==1?myTitles=myTitles.sprintf(' %g,%g',$3,$4):0) \
         index i w lp pt 7 ps 2 lc i+1, \
     for [i=1:words(myTitles)] '+' u (NaN):(NaN) every ::::0 \
         w lp pt 7 ps 2 lc i ti word(myTitles,i)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]